# Функция должна удалить из массива все простые числа и вернуть указатель на новый динамический массив

Tags: c++, функции, динамические-массивы, простые-числа

*Вопрос: Написать функцию, которая получает указатель на динамический массив и его размер. Функция должна удалить из массива все простые числа и вернуть указатель на новый динамический массив.
Размер первого рабочего массива вводиться пользователем, а элементы массива заполняются случайным образом.*
**Я сам не понял как задать условие и код не додумал,единственное что знаю что можно код "облегчить" при помощи Решето Эратосфена но как с массивом его использовать понять пока не могу,если возможно я бы хотел не использовать дополнительные библиотеки кроме iostream**
**1. Можно ли изменять переданный массив(Да); 2. Какого размера массив создавать (Вернуть массив размер которого равен количеству элементов без простых чисел)**

Comment: Уже спрашивали. И снова вы не указали 1. Можно ли изменять переданный массив; 2. Какого размера массив создавать (если не того же размера - то нужно же, наверное, вернуть размер нового массива?) Про "*дополнительные*" библиотеки - я опять же спрашивал о *стандартной библиотеке С++*, ну да ладно, считаем, что вы имеете в виду под "дополнительной" именно ее... Будьте добры, уточните задание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помня, что вы все же что-то делали в предыдущем вопросе, так что это не чисто "сделайте за меня" :), вот вам простейшее решение:

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
        if (n%i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

int * killPrimes(int * a, int& N)
{
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (!isPrime(a[i]))
            a[j++] = a[i];
    }
    int * b = new int[N = j];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 40;
    int a[40];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << (a[i] = rand()%30) << " ";
    cout << endl;

    int * b = killPrimes(a,N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

Функцию  `bool isPrime(int n)` можно написать как минимум в 2 раза эффективнее, но это уже вы сами, как домашнее задание :)

Comment: `i * i <= n` в общем-то нехорошо. Для типа int правильно работает до 46340 (дальше переполнение) / Конечно, при заполнении массива `... % 30` ошибок не будет, но кто-нибудь может копипастнуть и дальше нарваться ...

Comment: @avp  А зачем вам больше?